# Complete curves in $\mathcal{M}_g$ all of whose Jacobians have trivial endomorpism ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces, jacobians

I'm trying to construct complete smooth curves $C$ in $\overline{M}_g$ such that for all points $S \in C \cap \mathcal{M}_g$, its Jacobian $\text{Jac}(S)$ satisfies $\text{End}(\text{Jac}(S)) = \mathbb{Z}$.  Does anyone know a source of these?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  You used the letter $C$ to denote the base curve in the compactified moduli space $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$.  Then you used the same letter for the curves whose Jacobians you study.  Did you intend to write that the Jacobians of the (varying) fiber curves should all have "trivial" endomorphism algebra?

Comment: @JasonStarr I think Gina meant to ask about Jac(S) instead of Jac(C). I went ahead and corrected the body of the question.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Your interpretation is correct.  Sorry for the typo!  I read it multiple times before posting, but somehow the eye always manages to fill in what it wants to see rather than what is there...

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: Thanks for correcting that!

Comment: I have a related question.  Is it true that for a general point p = [C] in M_g, we have that the endomorphism ring of Jac(C) is Z?